# How to select radio buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery

The code below adds a value into a textbox:

```
$('#mainTxtWeight').val(textWeight);
```

But what I want know is how can I select a radio button depending on what a value is using jquery?

Below is the radio buttons:

```
<table id="replies">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Replies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Replies:</td>
        <td align="left">
            <div class="replytd">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="reply" id="singlebtn " value="single" class="replyBtn"
                    />Single</label>
            </div>
            <div class="replytd">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="reply" id="multiplebtn" value="multiple" class="replyBtn"
                    />Multiple</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have created an if statement below, I just need help being able to select "Single" radio button if Reply Type equals "Single", or select "Multiple" radio button if reply Type equals "Multiple".

Below is if statement:

```
if(reply == "Single") {
    //select "Single" radio button
} else if(reply == "Multiple") {
    //select "Multiple" radio button
}
```

I want the exact same thing to occur with this line of code as well which is again "Single" and "Multiple" radio buttons:

```
var $btnReply = "<input type='radio' name='reply[" + count + "]' value='single' class='replyBtnRow' /> Single<br /><input type='radio' name='reply[" + count + "]' value='multiple' class='replyBtnRow' /> Multiple";

$replies.children().append($btnReply);

if($("input[name=reply]:checked").length) {
    $replies.find('input[name="reply[' + count + ']"]').eq($("input[name=reply]:checked").val() == "single" ? 0 : 1).prop("checked", true);
}
```

UPDATE:

```
function addwindow(reply) { 


    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 

        $('input[value="'+reply.toLowerCase()+'"]').attr('checked', true);
        } else { 
            $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input[value="'+reply.toLowerCase()+'"]').attr('checked', true);
            }

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the radio button which has a value of what's in reply, which if I understand your question correctly, you can try this

```
$('input[value="'+reply.toLowerCase()+'"]')​.attr('checked', true)
```

assuming reply will always be 'single' or 'multiple'

Comment: same as above comment, do I not need if statement with this code?

Comment: No, you don't. when the function executes, the selector will look like this `input[value="single"]` or `input[value="multiple"]` depending on what reply is. if the field was found, it will mark it as checked. Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/9MNGV/

Comment: I have included an update of the code which contains your line of code, problem is I am getting an error stating "reply is undefined" and it is pointing to your line of code, do you know why this is because it seems fine to me?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing how the 'addWindow' function is called. Is it an event handler? If you are calling it, make sure it's called in this manner `addWindow('Multiple')`. If it's an event handler, completely different story

Comment: addwindow is an onclick event. Does that mean it should be addWindow('Multiple','Single') because this is giving me a formal parameter error?

Comment: Something like this.. `$('#whatever').on('click', function(e) {  e.preventDefault(); addWindow('Multiple'); // add your logic to figure out if it's multiple or single before calling addWindow  })`

Comment: Where you put #whatever, what is that suppose to be?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="reply"]').filter('[value="' + reply.toLowerCase() + '"]')
                        .attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: so I do not need the if statement at all?

Comment: Nope, you already have the selector you need in the `reply` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(reply == "Single")
    $("#singlebtn").attr('checked',true);

else if(reply == "Multiple")
    $("#multiplebtn").attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: How do I check buttons for bottom example, as that they don't have an id so how do we say if "Single" select the single radio button else select the multiple radio button?

Comment: Replace `else if(reply == "Multiple")` with just `else`. Now, if variable `reply` is equal to `Single`, the `singlebtn` will be checked, but if variable `reply` is not equal to `Single`, the `multiplebtn` will be checked. `reply` doesn't have to be equal to `Multiple`.

Comment: No I mean what Im saying is that if you look at my question, if you look at the code above the UPDATE code, you will see that there is another 2 radio buttons, both Single and Multiple but thy don't contain an id, so can't use #singlebtn or #multiplebtn, so how can I check those radio buttons?